# How to add hover effects on different elements from the same div

Tags: html, css, hover, effects

Hey everyone this is my first time posting here.
My question is how can I add different hover effects on elements from a div.

I have a div that contains 3 elements: an image, a button, and a paragraph, I already have a scale effect on the div to change the size of the whole container but I would also want to change the color of the button when hovering anywhere on the div, not necessarily on the button. The same applies to the image.

The div:

```
<div class="float_tab">
      <img src="./NY_2.jpeg" alt="imagine"/>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel ipsum autem, sed aut sunt repellat laudantium aspernatur fugiat dolorem.</p>
      <input class="btn" value="Enter" type="button">
    </div>
```

The stylization

```css
    .float_tab:hover{
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    .float_tab {
      width: 210px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: rgb(128, 177, 220, 0.7);
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      top:-1500px;
      left: 570px;
      margin-right: 100px;
      transition: 1s;
    
    }
    img {
      width: 210px;
      height: 120px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    
    }
    
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    
    .btn {
      height: 20px;
      width: 90px;
      margin-left: 60px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background-color: #80b1dc;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css will only apply effects to matching elements so:

```
<script>
    .float_tab:hover img{
        //css here
    }
    
    .float_tab:hover .btn{
        //css here
    }
</script>

<div class="float_tab">
      <img src="./NY_2.jpeg" alt="imagine"/>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel ipsum autem, sed aut sunt repellat laudantium aspernatur fugiat dolorem.</p>
      <input class="btn" value="Enter" type="button">
</div>
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a new style for child elements:

```
.float_tab:hover input, img {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

An example:

```css
.float_tab:hover input, img{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
 <div class="float_tab">
    <img alt="foo image" alt="imagine" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel ipsum autem, sed aut sunt repellat
      laudantium aspernatur fugiat dolorem.</p>
    <input class="btn" value="Enter" type="button">
  </div>
```